# How can I allow JSSOR to use ng-repeats in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, jssor

I'm pretty new to the Angular game, and I have been trying to integrate a JSSOR slider into my webpage which would utilize AngularJS's ng-repeat feature using a custom directive.  So far, I have tested in Devtools and cannot find any errors in the console when I load the page with the slider on it, and I paused as it loaded to make sure that all of my images were loading in the ng-repeat as I would have hoped, but JSSOR only displays the first picture in a strange position compared to where it should be and doesn't have any animation.  I know that my app, directives, and controllers are all doing what they're supposed to, but I'm guessing it's something in how JSSOR finds the div with the img's in it that it will display that's tripping it up.  Any suggestions?

HTML from within JSSOR Slideshow:

```
<div class="slideShow">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div class="containPic" u="slides" style="display: block; cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; overflow: hidden;">
        <slider-pic></slider-pic>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML from slider-pic directive:

```
<div ng-controller="SliderController">
    <div ng-repeat="photo in livePhotos">
        <img u="image" ng-src="img/full-size/live/{{photo.pic}}" />
        <img u="thumb" ng-src="img/thumbnail/live/{{photo.thumb}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DId you find a solution on this?

Comment: Not yet.  I have put it on the backburner for now and just went with having the JSSOR slideshow on one of my template pages without using ng-repeat for the pictures.  I tried using https://github.com/adebisi-fa/dang-jssor, but it didn't work for my purposes.  Still hoping to find a way to include it utilizing ng-repeat, JSSOR is a great slider but I'd like to make the pictures easier to update and add to.